# "Hello World" example for Slick 2.0 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

Is there an example of how to use the Slick 2.0.1 library for Scala to connect to a MySQL database? I could not find up-to-date examples with Googling...

Recently, I have been thinking about porting the code for the web application that I have been developing with PHP into Scala. I have been looking for a programming language that has (i) a web application framework with a good number of users, (ii) offers compile time error-checking, (iii) nice testing tools, and so on... After reading about some case studies (*e.g.,* [huffpost](http://www.typesafe.com/blog/huffington-post-case-study-building-a-solid-platform-with-typesafe) and [cousera](http://www.typesafe.com/blog/making-online-education-accessible-with-typesafe)) of developing web applications using Scala and Play framework, it started looking appealing to me and I decided to give it a shot.

As all the data from the previous project reside in a MySQL database, I was looking at what Scala offers for my program to connect to MySQL. I came across Slick. I followed the [Hello-Slick example](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-slick) in the Typesafe Activator, which guided me how to use an in-memory database (*i.e.,* h2) and I liked its syntax and the level of abstraction. Now, I want to use Slick with MySQL. I tried changing the import statements

`import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._`

to

`import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._`

in both `HelloSlick.scala` and `Tables.scala` in the aforementioned example (please see the full copy of the code below). However, I am getting the following error message when I compile it:

> /Users/kotaro/Documents/Scala/hello-slick/src/test/scala/TablesSuite.scala
>
> value ddl is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery[Suppliers]
>
> def createSchema() = (suppliers.ddl ++ coffees.ddl).create
>
> ```
>                               ^
> ```

Does anyone know what is causing this? According to this post ([slick exception when trying to connect to MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229561/slick-exception-when-trying-to-connect-to-mysql/22230129#22230129)), I might be missing to add some dependencies though the error message I'm getting is different. If there is a good example that I can follow to get a grasp of how to use Slick with MySQL, that would help a lot too.

I am using Scala 2.10.3, MySQL in XAMPP 1.7.3 with OS X 10.8 and JRE 1.6.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Following is the full copy of the code.

HelloSlick.scala

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
//import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

// The main application
object HelloSlick extends App {

  // The query interface for the Suppliers table
  val suppliers: TableQuery[Suppliers] = TableQuery[Suppliers]

  // the query interface for the Coffees table
  val coffees: TableQuery[Coffees] = TableQuery[Coffees]

  // Create a connection (called a "session") to an in-memory H2 database
  Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user="root", password="").withSession { implicit session =>

  // Create the schema by combining the DDLs for the Suppliers and Coffees tables using the query interfaces
    (suppliers.ddl ++ coffees.ddl).create


    /* Create / Insert */

    // Insert some suppliers
    suppliers += (101, "Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199")
    suppliers += (49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place", "Mendocino", "CA", "95460")
    suppliers += (150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966")

    // Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature)
    val coffeesInsertResult: Option[Int] = coffees ++= Seq (
      ("Colombian",         101, 7.99, 0, 0),
      ("French_Roast",       49, 8.99, 0, 0),
      ("Espresso",          150, 9.99, 0, 0),
      ("Colombian_Decaf",   101, 8.99, 0, 0),
      ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
    )

    val allSuppliers: List[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = suppliers.list

    // Print the number of rows inserted
    coffeesInsertResult foreach (numRows => println(s"Inserted $numRows rows into the Coffees table"))


    /* Read / Query / Select */

    // Print the SQL for the Coffees query
    println("Generated SQL for base Coffees query:\n" + coffees.selectStatement)

    // Query the Coffees table using a foreach and print each row
    coffees foreach { case (name, supID, price, sales, total) =>
      println("  " + name + "\t" + supID + "\t" + price + "\t" + sales + "\t" + total)
    }


    /* Filtering / Where */

    // Construct a query where the price of Coffees is > 9.0
    val filterQuery: Query[Coffees, (String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = coffees.filter(_.price > 9.0)

    println("Generated SQL for filter query:\n" + filterQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(filterQuery.list)


    /* Update */

    // Construct an update query with the sales column being the one to update
    val updateQuery: Query[Column[Int], Int] = coffees.map(_.sales)

    // Print the SQL for the Coffees update query
    println("Generated SQL for Coffees update:\n" + updateQuery.updateStatement)

    // Perform the update
    val numUpdatedRows = updateQuery.update(1)

    println(s"Updated $numUpdatedRows rows")


    /* Delete */

    // Construct a delete query that deletes coffees with a price less than 8.0
    val deleteQuery: Query[Coffees,(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0)

    // Print the SQL for the Coffees delete query
    println("Generated SQL for Coffees delete:\n" + deleteQuery.deleteStatement)

    // Perform the delete
    val numDeletedRows = deleteQuery.delete

    println(s"Deleted $numDeletedRows rows")


    /* Selecting Specific Columns */

    // Construct a new coffees query that just selects the name
    val justNameQuery: Query[Column[String], String] = coffees.map(_.name)

    println("Generated SQL for query returning just the name:\n" + justNameQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(justNameQuery.list)


    /* Sorting / Order By */

    val sortByPriceQuery: Query[Coffees, (String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = coffees.sortBy(_.price)

    println("Generated SQL for query sorted by price:\n" + sortByPriceQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(sortByPriceQuery.list)


    /* Query Composition */

    val composedQuery: Query[Column[String], String] = coffees.sortBy(_.name).take(3).filter(_.price > 9.0).map(_.name)

    println("Generated SQL for composed query:\n" + composedQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the composed query
    println(composedQuery.list)


    /* Joins */

    // Join the tables using the relationship defined in the Coffees table
    val joinQuery: Query[(Column[String], Column[String]), (String, String)] = for {
      c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
      s <- c.supplier
    } yield (c.name, s.name)

    println("Generated SQL for the join query:\n" + joinQuery.selectStatement)

    // Print the rows which contain the coffee name and the supplier name
    println(joinQuery.list)


    /* Computed Values */

    // Create a new computed column that calculates the max price
    val maxPriceColumn: Column[Option[Double]] = coffees.map(_.price).max

    println("Generated SQL for max price column:\n" + maxPriceColumn.selectStatement)

    // Execute the computed value query
    println(maxPriceColumn.run)


    /* Manual SQL / String Interpolation */

    // Required import for the sql interpolator
    import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.interpolation

    // A value to insert into the statement
    val state = "CA"

    // Construct a SQL statement manually with an interpolated value
    val plainQuery = sql"select SUP_NAME from SUPPLIERS where STATE = $state".as[String]

    println("Generated SQL for plain query:\n" + plainQuery.getStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(plainQuery.list)

  }
}
```

Tables.scala

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, ForeignKeyQuery}


// A Suppliers table with 6 columns: id, name, street, city, state, zip
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name: Column[String] = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street: Column[String] = column[String]("STREET")
  def city: Column[String] = column[String]("CITY")
  def state: Column[String] = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip: Column[String] = column[String]("ZIP")
  
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}

// A Coffees table with 5 columns: name, supplier id, price, sales, total
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name: Column[String] = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price: Column[Double] = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total: Column[Int] = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  
  def * : ProvenShape[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = (name, supID, price, sales, total)
  
  // A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
  def supplier: ForeignKeyQuery[Suppliers, (Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = 
    foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, TableQuery[Suppliers])(_.id)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably overlooked that the error message refers to `TableSuite.scala``

```
/Users/kotaro/Documents/Scala/hello-slick/src/test/scala/TablesSuite.scala

value ddl is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery[Suppliers]

def createSchema() = (suppliers.ddl ++ coffees.ddl).create
```

You need to change the import in there as well.